# delete folder and contents with Powershell

Tags: powershell, recursion, parent-child

I'm trying to delete the contents of the users folder. It works for files but it leaves folders. How can I take folders with it? This is what i have tried using powershell:

```
$folders = @(
"C:\Users\*\Downloads\*",
"C:\Users\*\Downloads\*.*", 
"C:\Users\*\Documents\*.*", 
"C:\Users\*\Documents\*.*", 
"C:\Users\*\Pictures\*",
"C:\Users\*\Pictures\*.*",
"C:\Users\*\Desktop\*",
"C:\Users\*\Desktop\*.*",
"C:\Users\*\Videos\*",
"C:\Users\*\Videos\*.*")
foreach ($folder in $folders) {Remove-Item $folder -force -recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}
exit 0
```

How can i take parents folders in those folders and their child elemetns? I want complete empty Document, desktop etc.

Comment: If I run that command for a folder, it will delete everything under it and the folder itself. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Really? that is odd. Because for me, i have a folde rin my documents which it doesnt touch but it does delete files  in the root of the documents.

Comment: Remove the -ErrorAction and look at the full output. Confirm you have permissions to delete it.

Comment: Im running it through a 3rd party tool which has elevated privilegs. It should delete the folders as well right

Comment: @ZK-2500z "Should" yes, but it doesn't. So please turn on any error reporting like Taylor suggested and look at them. It does not have to be a problem with permissions, but may be special characters? Error messages will tell you...

Comment: I am getting unautherized acces. the tool im using has acces but the system user doesnt appearantly. would it be wise to temp change the sign permission?

Comment: I have gotten,    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException 
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

Answer (score 0):

I got it, im slightly stupid in my script i noted:

"C:\Users*\Documents*.*",
"C:\Users*\Documents*.*",

rip and that was the folder i was working with.. RIP! i changed it to

"C:\Users*\Documents*",
"C:\Users*\Documents*.*",

now it works!! thanks